# Spacing in the table of contents - change row

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I need to change the spacing between the changes in a row. 6pt Spacing must be between 
- 2.2 and 2.2.1 
- 2.3 and 2.2.2.

[image]

Use the comment

```
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip6pt}
```

Unfortunately it does not work as I want.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `\cftbeforesubsubsecskip` and `\cftaftersubsubsecskip` parameters via `\setlength` directives?

Comment: Yes. It does not work as it should. http://i.imgur.com/nQgSW0m.png

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution, using some conditional test: a redefinition of `\subsection` tests whether to add or not the spacing before the subsection entry; if it's the first subsection, space is added, otherwise, not. A redefinition of `\section` tests whether to add or not the spacing before the section entry; if subsections appeared before, space is added, otherwise, no extra space is added.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\ifnum\value{subsection}>0\relax\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{6pt}}\else\fi\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>1\relax\else\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{6pt}}\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\section{Test Section Three}

\end{document}
```

[image]